# IOS: Not able to access my label in UICell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring

I am trying to create a table with prototype cell
for that i had taken a tableview and inserted a cell in table view 
and in cell i had taken a label in which i want to set values from my Employee class.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RWTCell *cell = (RWTCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"employeeeCell"];
    if (!cell){
        cell = [[RWTCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"employeeeCell"];
    }
    Employee *currentEmp=[employeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"  %@",currentEmp.empName);
    cell.lName.text=currentEmp.empName;
//    cell.textLabel.text = currentEmp.empName;

    return cell;

}
```

Above is my code
when i try to do

```
RWTCell *cell = (RWTCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"employeeeCell"];
```

it always gives me null, and this line below never works

```
cell.lName.text=currentEmp.empName;
```

my Employee.m class

```
#import "Employee.h"

@implementation Employee
    @synthesize empDepart,empDoj,empDob,empName,empSalary,empGender;
@end
```

and Employee.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Employee : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *empName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *empSalary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *empDob;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *empDoj;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *empGender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *empDepart;

@end
```

**EDIT**
sorry i forgot to mention my cell class
and i am working on storyboard

```
#import "RWTCell.h"

    @implementation RWTCell
    @synthesize lName;
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @end



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RWTCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lName;
@end
```

Comment: What is done in RWTCell class?

Comment: Have you verified that both `cell.lName` and `currentEmp.empName` are not `nil`?

Comment: RWTCell is the class which i had made

Comment: @rmaddy no only cell is nil

Comment: try to alloc, init your UILabel in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method. then see.

Comment: @user3431723 : I have added some reference code in answer can you please check if you have followed those things?

Comment: Are you sure you declaring the Cell Reuse Identifier is employeeeCell? When you use Prototype Cell, you dont need to the  code:if (!cell){
        cell = [[RWTCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"employeeeCell"];
    }

Comment: @user3431723 How can `cell` be `nil`? You create the cell in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you connected your custom cell with your view at RWTCell.xib

At your .h file

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) RWTCell *rwtcell;

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier= @"MyIdentifier";
    RWTCell *cell = (RWTCell*)[tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RWTCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=self.rwtcell;
    }
    Employee *currentEmp=[employeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"  %@",currentEmp.empName);
    cell.lName.text=currentEmp.empName;
    return cell;
    }
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the custom cell I am using in my application.

.h file of custom cell

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EvalHistoryCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblEvaluator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblStore;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblStatus;

@end
```

.m file of custom cell

```
#import "EvalHistoryCell.h"

@implementation EvalHistoryCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
@end
```

in main viewcontroller where you want to use it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *strEvalIdentifier = @"HistoryIdentifier";

 EvaluationListEntity *objEvalEntity=[arrmEvalList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  EvalHistoryCell *cell = (EvalHistoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strEvalIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EvalHistoryCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
 cell.lblEvaluator.text=objEvalEntity.strEvaluatorName;
  return cell;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Also you have to create XIB file for that custom cell having all those IBOutlets set to the respective views.